# Best way to check for updates with an HTTP Get Request

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I'm programming something in Java that requires me to periodically check for updates from a server. Currently I'm using Apache HTTPClient, and performing a GET request every second. This seems to be inefficient. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: inefficient in what way?

Comment: so it's not inefficient? Seriously I have no idea, I was just wondering if there is a better way.